# Java - How to search a string and assign a class?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have 4 categories of words related to travel domain.
Eg: -

```
ACCOMMODATION = {"hotel","restaurant","cafe","tea shop","lodging","coffee"}
COST = {"costly","expensive","price","inexpensive","fee","ticket"}
AMBIANCE = {"ambiance","ambience","cool","warm","hot"}
TRANSPORT = {"car","van","ride","walk","traffic","travel","road"}
```

I also have a list of sentences, what I want is to search each of these sentences and check for any of the above keywords present in the sentence. If so, tag the relevant category/categories with the sentence so that final output would be something like;

```
sentence1 [tab] ACCOMMODATION,COST
sentence2 [tab] ACCOMMODATION
sentence3 [tab] TRANSPORT
```

How can I achieve this most efficiently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service, you are expected to attempt the solution and ask for help when you get stuck, showing what you've done and any errors you encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should split a sentence into words

```
Stream<String> words = Arrays.stream(sentence.split("\\s"));
```

Create HashSet for every category:

```
Set<String> transportWords = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("car","van","ride","walk","traffic","travel","road"));
Set<String> costWords = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("costly","expensive","price","inexpensive","fee","ticket"));
```

and map them to category:

```
Map<Set<String>, Category>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(transportWords, Category.TRANSPORT);
map.put(costWords, Category.TRANSPORT);
```

Then iterate over sentence words and check if they belong to a category

```
Set<Category> categories = Arrays.stream(sentence.split("\\s"))
        .map(s -> {
            for (Set<String> keywords : map.keySet()) {
                if (keywords.contains(s)) {
                    return Optional.of(map.get(keywords));
                }
            }
            return Optional.<Category>empty();
        })
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```